# View can't see instance variable defined in ApplicationController, in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, instance-variables

Hey guys! I'm getting a problem that is driving me crazy.

I defined an instance variable inside my `ApplicationController`:

```
def initialize
    @stylesheets = []
end
```

When I try to access it from a view, say SomeNamespace::SiteSection (index.html.erb):

```
<% @stylesheets << "some-stylesheet" %>
<h1>Blablabla</h1>
```

the instance variable `@stylesheets` isn't visible, i.e., ruby says it wasn't defined.

So, how I make this instance variable visible inside the views?

Thanks in advance.

Additional info:

- I'm using ruby 1.9.2 with rails 3.0.4
- I'm using namespaces (the `ApplicationController` isn't namespaced)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :set_var

  private
  def set_var
    @stylesheets = []
  end
end
```